# How to make python3 the default version on WING IDE

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, python3

I'm new to python and I've been trying to update from python 2 to 3 by doing `apt-get install python3` and it installed but when I type `python --version` on my terminal the version is 2.7.9. How can I uninstall python2 and make python3 the default version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wing IDE has a configuration dialog box where you can set the path to your preferred python interpreter, over-riding the default.

To do so, select the `Custom` radio-button for `Python Executable` in the `Project Properties` dialog box and then either entering a path or clicking on the `Browse` button.

The `Project Properties` dialog is apparently accessible from the `Project` menu and the toolbar.

More info at https://wingware.com/doc/intro/tutorial-python-path

Answer (score 1):

`python2` and `python3` are incompatible with each other, and a lot of the software only work with `python2`. So, `apt-get` does not overwrite `python2` when you install `python3`.
You should call Python3 with `python3` command and use `#!/usr/bin/python3` as the shebang in your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run python3 instead of python, python2 is still installed on your system.

Comment: okay I see, so the question should be how to remove python 2

Comment: You can remove the "python" package using apt-get remove python.
You can check which file belongs to which package using dpkg -S .. e.g dpkg -S \`which python\`

Comment: I just read doing so is not a good idea, because a lot of things on my system are using python2 for functionality. I'm trying to make python3 the default version for Wing IDE

Comment: Or `#!/usr/bin/env python3`